# Natbib does not work in elsarticle

Tags: bibtex, natbib, elsarticle

I have found answers to similar questions but none solved my problem. I am not able to get references in a document produced by elsarticle.

For example I fail getting the references when doing as in the following question. elsarticle and natbib problem

But when running BibTeX I get the error message: ERROR - Cannot find control file 'documentname.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1

I have the same problem when running the template provided by Elsevier.

Comment: (1) welcome to the site, (2) please provide a full but minimal example of what you are doing. It is pretty clear from that message that you are using `biblatex` but that is not listed elsewhere in your question. And if you are using `biblatex` you should not also be using `natbib`. Additionally, if this is going to be sent to Elsevier, I'd double check if `biblatex` is something they support.

Comment: The `elsarticle` document class loads the `natbib` package *automatically*. `natbib` is not compatible with `biblatex`, though. By implication, the `elsarticle` document class is not compatible with `biblatex`. Does your document preamble maybe contain an instruction such as `\usepackage{biblatex}`?

Comment: On Elsevier templates with `natbib` you need to run BibTeX instead of Biber. The error message you quote is from Biber and not from BibTeX. Presumably you need to tell your editor to run BibTeX instead of Biber, sort of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 in reverse.

Comment: Probably `nonatbib` option `(\documentclass[nonatbib]{elsarticle})` should help to skip loading `natbib` package.

Comment: Thank you @moewe this worked for me. You can promote your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Elsevier templates don't use `biblatex`, usually they load `natbib` by default. I don't think it is advisable to try and use `biblatex` with `elsarticle` or any other Elsevier template.

That means that you need to compile your document with BibTeX and not with Biber. Tell your editor to run BibTeX instead of Biber. (I.e. do [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) in reverse.)